# line break in csv file content

Tags: magento, csv, line-breaks

Guys i need to create a very simple csv file with some product details in order to import them to an online shopping site. Each product has 3 attributes: name, description and price.

The csv file would look like this:

product 1,product description,100
product 2,product description,100
product 3,product description,100

I have 2 problems:

1) each product description has more than one line, something like

```
  This the product's description.
  This is a cool feature.
  This is another feature.
  Product made in the US.
```

How can i keep/add this formatting in the csv file?

2) second problem, most product descriptions contain a comma "," in there, like:
      This product is great, reliable and also cheap.

How can i add these commas to the description without breaking the csv format?

And a final question: some product descriptions have more than 800 or even 100 characters. Is it possible to add that much characters in a field in a csv?

Comment: What's reading the CSV file? Line length shouldn't matter. Some programs may allow `\n` to appear in a field to indicate a linefeed (newline). Others do not. Some may allow `\,` or quotes to escape/contain a literal comma; others do not. CSV is not a universal standard format; it's an umbrella term for fields separated by commas. The exact implementation for CSV readers varies widely.

Comment: tried to add \n (doesn't work), tried to add \, (it adds a \ to my text and moves to the next one)

Comment: Unfortunately it may not be possible. I suggest you try to contact support for the online shopping site and ask about their CSV format; they may be the only ones who know if it's possible and how. Also ask them if they support any other import formats (XML?) which might allow you more flexibility in your field values.

Comment: Just enclose text into double quotes and your comas will be preserved.

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it seems pointless trying to suggest anything if you already know the parser in question neither accepts newlines within fields nor honours double quotes to "hold fields together" and you have no possibility to alter its behaviour. All that happens is that I get downvoted for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP_EOL`. This will add new line in the export csv cell.

```
$mycustomHtml .= PHP_EOL . $name;
```

Answer (score -1):

A workaround for the first problem is to use HTML `<br/>` tags instead of line breaks. That's what I'm doing, at least until I find a better solution.

So you would change:

```
This the product's description.
This is a cool feature.
This is another feature.
Product made in the US.
```

to:

```
This the product's description.<br/>This is a cool feature.<br/>This is another feature.<br/>Product made in the US.
```

As for the second problem: in my tests, Magento didn't seem to have any trouble with commas within fields. But you can always change the delimiter Magento uses. I usually use tab (\t). Make sure to use Magento's advanced import features in `System > Import/Export > Dataflow-Profiles`.